# How to display image stored in Ios documentsDirectory , cordova / ionic2

Tags: cordova, ionic2

I am currently developing Ionic2 app. I have created a directory say, CBSAP using `cordova.file.documentsDirectory` , I downloaded few PNG files in it. Now when I try to give img src = this.fs/CBSAP/aa.png, ios give error as resource not found. But same code works for Android.

Please help, how can I set img > src as external directory in Ionic2 app.